# How to put result of directory search in variable?

Tags: windows, cmd, windows-console

I want to use `dir` command to search files (there will be only one file that match) and after that I want to put result of search (found file) in variable.

Reason for doing thinks like this is pretty simple. I want to avoid to put full directory after `cd`.

Please help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question isn't clear.

```
for /f "delims=" %A in ('dir c:\windows\*.ini') do Echo %A
```

Comment: make this a good answer: `dir /s /b C:\startdir\*.ini` looks in `c:\startdir\ ` and it's subdirectories for a file that matches `*.ini`, which (I think) OP wants to do. Also you should mention, that in batchfiles, the `%` should be doubled.

Comment: All I want to do is A=(file directory) and Then cd A to go to tnie specific directory ... Is this possible???